# Firefox showing tiny web pages

Tags: windows-8, parallels, macbook-pro-retina

I'm running Windows 8 on a Retina MacBook through Parallels.

When I launch Mozilla Firefox, all web content is shown really small on my screen. For example, this website takes up about a third of the horizontal screen real estate available.

How can I show web content at a reasonable size? Do I have to zoom right in every time I open the browser?

Comment: You're saying you have to re-zoom in every time you open up Firefox?

Comment: I have to re-zoom for every new website I visit. Zoom level also seems to be lost between reboots.

Comment: Is it just FF that's acting this way, and fine in IE?

Comment: FF is the only browser with this issue. IE and Chrome are not affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the addons Caleb suggested, you could fiddle with Firefox's configuration. Navigate to `about:config`. Use the search bar at the top of the page.

- `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`

  This controls pixel scaling. Change to a higher value to enlarge everything in the Firefox window.
- `browser.zoom.siteSpecific`

  This turns off site specific zoom, so one zoom level is used across all sites. Caleb's suggested addons allow finer control, with a default global zoom in addition to site specific zoom.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible solutions

1. Reset Zoom by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero key)
2. Install the [Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6965) AddOn
3. Install the [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2592/) AddOn

[Source](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/872490). You can find more information [here](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=firefox%20zoomed%20out&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=firefox%20zoomed%20out).

Answer (score 2):

Firefox V22 (June 2013) now has support for high DPI settings in Windows so you no longer need to preform the config changes. It will correctly scale by default.

If you have made the suggested DPI change in Firefox, just update Firefox and go back into

> about:config

Find the settings you changed, right-click and select "Reset". You'll now be back to standard config.

You'll also see the Firefox app menus are now correctly sized and laid out. :)